# Animation component can't change Image Source but Animator can

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I have a UI Image with animation. I want to use sprite a sheet as animation.

When I use Animator Component and drag&drop all images it works perfectly. But when I use Animation Component it doesn't work.

Doesn't work:

[image: Doesn't work]

Works:

[image: Works]

Any idea why?